# Two SBS 2003 Servers, two domains, one company, Exchange, and Terminal Services

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2003, windows-sbs-2003, windows-terminal-services, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Here's the scenario; please let me know if I haven't provided enough info.

Business 1 went out of business, and their assets were purchased by Business 2.

Business 1 had an SBS 2003 server (Server1), set up with AD/DNS/DHCP, is the DC for domain1, and is sharing files.  No Exchange or TS.

Business 2 has an SBS 2003 server (Server2), set up with Exchange/AD/DNS/DHCP, is the DC for domain2, and doing file sharing.  No TS.
Business 2 also has a Server 2008 Std. machine (Server3), set up with Terminal Services, for users to log in and use one particular application.

When we moved Biz2 to Biz1's building, we turned off DNS and DHCP on the Biz1 SBS server (Server1). Member computers/users for Business 1 are still using it to login to their domain (domain1).  Biz2's SBS server (Server2) is DNS/DHCP for the entire network, and is still the DC for domain2.  I realize this is not ideal, but it works, for now.

Question 1: What are my options to "merge" the two domains?  We'll be moving away from domain1, and onto domain2 for everything eventually, but that will take a bit of work.  Do I make Server1 just a member server, or can't I do that with SBS?

Question 2: Can I move the TS licenses from Server3 to one of the SBS servers?  We need to re-purpose Server3 for a different (dedicated) application.

Thanks in advance, please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Why the WS2008 tag?

Answer (score 1):

1. The two SBS servers wont live on the same network unless they're Premium. Then it takes some additional configuration.
2. Unless you've got the licenses on paper, or have access to them electronically, you don't really have those licenses. If you've got access to the license keys than its just a matter of setting up the licensing service. I'd recommend doing some virtualization and a P2V on the 2008 server, that way you don't have to worry about transferring licenses around.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with password changes for all of Biz1 users, I've had good luck moving users over with [ldifde](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237677).

Can't help you on the TS license.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can have two 2008 SBS Premium servers on one domain, you cannot do that with SBS 2003. Simply put: Only one SBS server per domain, but you can add member servers.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884453 ("Only one SBS server can exist on the domain. If SBS 2003 is installed, no other SBS 2003 or 2000 server can be installed on the same domain.")

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469604(WS.10).aspx ("You can add only one additional server from Windows SBS 2008 Premium into a Windows SBS 2008 domain. The second server that comes with Windows SBS 2008 Premium must run only in a Windows SBS 2008 domain. You cannot use it as a standalone operating system that is not joined to the Windows SBS 2008 domain or promote it as the domain controller of a new domain in the Active Directory forest.")

I would still call Microsoft licensing to be 100% sure. Just call sales: it is a pre-sales question. Your user CAL's are probably going to be a sticking point so go into that with them in detail.